# Gazebo custom mesh not showing shadow

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-11

This seems like a silly issue that I am having, but I am trying to use a custom mesh as the ground for my simulation. I have generated a .dae file containing the following  tag:

```
<phong>
            <emission>
              <color>.7 .7 0.7 1.0</color>
            </emission>
            <ambient>
              <color>0.50 0.50 0.50 1.0</color>
            </ambient>
            <diffuse>
              <color>0.50 0.50 0.50 1.0</color>
            </diffuse>
            <specular>
              <color>0.50 0.50 0.50 .50</color>
            </specular>
            <shininess>
              <float>0.50</float>
            </shininess>
            <reflective>
              <color>0.50 0.50 0.50 1.0</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>0.50</float>
            </reflectivity>
            <transparent>
              <color>0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0</color>
            </transparent>
            <transparency>
              <float>1.0</float>
            </transparency>
          </phong>
```

But when I render the scene I get this:
[image: gazebo sim with no shadows]
Which is great! I am glad the mesh is being imported, but I can't see the ridges when I am viewing the mesh. I have also included my '.world' file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <world name="default">
    <light name='light_source1' type='directional'>
      <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      <pose frame=''>0.25 0 10 0 -0.7854 0</pose>
      <attenuation>
       <range>1000</range>
        <constant>0.9</constant>
        <linear>0.01</linear>
        <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
      <diffuse>1 0 0 1</diffuse>
      <specular>1 0 0 1</specular>
      <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
    </light>
    <model name="my_mesh">
      <pose>-50 50 -10  1.57 0 0</pose>
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="body">
        <visual name="visual" >
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://temp_mesh.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://temp_mesh.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
      </link>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

I have tried adding directional and spot lights to no avail. I have also worked on making a texture for the mesh, but couldn't seem to get that to work either. Finally, I tried adding a light into the Collada file, but that seemed to have no effect either.